# How to delete page numbers at the end of every line with vim

Tags: vim

As you can see every line has either 2 or 3 digits and I want to delete them in vim.

```
Ruby 19
C++ 30
Pacal 15
Basic 106
PHP 112
Javascript 353
...
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$ # to the end of line
C-v # visual mode
G # to select up to the end of line
d # delete
```

How can I achieve this in vim?

Answer (score 3):

If you also want to delete the space before it:

`:%s/ [0-9]*$//`

Answer (score 1):

With `:normal`:

```
:%norm $daw
```

- `:normal` executes normal mode commands from the command-line.
- `$` moves the cursor to the end of the line.
- `daw` deletes the word under the cursor including the whitespace before.

Answer (score 1):

Blockwise visual mode doesn't work here, because the numbers aren't left-aligned.

You could use `$daw` (delete a word (including whitespace) at the end of the line), followed by `j` motion to the next line, or via

```
:%normal! $daw
```

But it's probably easier with a `:substitution`:

```
:%s/\s\+\d\+$//
```